# marginfigure: meaning of parameters 'pc'

Tags: floats

Please, what is the meaning of parameters 'pc' in the following line:

`\begin{marginfigure}[-15pc]`

thanks a lot, valerio

Comment: `pc` is pica an old printers name for 12pt unrelated to margins or floats any tex length can use that unit

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!